# Creating a % from two categorical variables (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have two variables, one is labor market status and it is listed as a count of people in each category:

```
LF_status      Freq. 

In_LF           100
Out_of_LF       20
```

And then an education categorical variable with the following groups:

```
educ                     Freq. 
no_HS                    30 
HS but not college       80
College                  10
```

I would like to visualize labor force participation as a % in each group. For instance, what % of those with a college degree are in the labor force, rather than using frequencies/counts. Essentially, I would like to know how labor force participation varies by one's education.

Currently my code is this and it produces something similar to the graph below:

```
graph hbar (count), over(lm_stat) over(educ)
```

[image]

Comment: See the help for `graph hbar` for calculation of percents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A community-contributed wrapper for `graph hbar` is `catplot` from SSC.

```
sysuse auto, clear 
catplot rep78 foreign, percent(foreign)
```

is a simple example.